# Power BI - Undesired Filters on Visual being Selected Automatically on All Charts in one Page

Tags: powerbi

I have this question during creating a power BI report with many pages, and this happens to only one page of this report.

Whenever I create a new chart in this page, the visual filter of this chart will automatically being set as "Year is not 2018", in this way, year 2018's data cannot be showed in any of the charts in this page while I want year 2018 to be showed. (The report should show data from 2018 to now.)

I'm not sure why this filter would appear here since no slicer non filter being selected by me to exclude data of 2018, and the raw data has 2018's data. The charts in other pages are working fine to show 2018. I'm wondering if anyone had this situation before and might know what has happed here?
Thanks a lot!

In this attached picture, the filter Year (is not 2018) appeared in the chart. If I create a new chart, this filter would also appear.

[image]

The below picture is what I have for this page's filter.

[image]

Right now, I really have no clue about the root cause of this. Any suggestions would be really appreciated, thank you in advance!